Can you put target value in input x in keras lstm model?
In keras documentation:
Arguments x:

A tf.data.Dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
A keras.utils.PyDataset returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

Does it mean that the target values can be included in the input variable x? I have seen an example that uses x. Would it make the model inaccurate? Thanks in advance.
Method:
Model.fit()
x=(1,2,target value), y=(target value)

Are you referring to the documentation for the fit method? There you need to provide x and y values separately or in the form of the dataset object. And of course you need the target values for the back propagation of the model

Yeah the fit method indeed.  So x=(1,2,target value), y=(target value), just wonder if this will work. Shouldn't the model have very strong weight in the x target value?

No, if you're providing target value as a part of a dataset, then you don't need to provide values for y

Its just an API convention, the model is not being given the target as input, its just convenience to use the fit API with the tf dataset API.

ah, i think i got it now, thanks!
